# Filter content using checkboxes & JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having problems making this code work:

```
    $(function(){
        $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
            var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
            //For each one checked
            $('input:checked').each(function() {
                    $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

With HTML like:

```
      <div class="tags">
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="arts" /> Arts </label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="computers" /> Computers </label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="health" /> Health </label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" /> Video Games </label>
      </div>
      <ul class="results">
         <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
         <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
         <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
         <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
      </ul>
```

I've tried it in IE, FF & Opera, but I don't get expected results. That is, the content is not being filtered upon clicking a checkbox? I'm trying to replicate something similar to this:

http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/Jeans+for+Women/302,default,sc.html

Notice the accordian effect on the left side bar of the page. I'm not too worried about the accordian itself, it's the checkboxes function that I'm focusing on at the moment. On page load, all query results (some 1300 or so), are displayed to the user.

A user can then filter or refine the results by clicking on checkboxes. I'm assuming this is some kind of Jquery/Ajax script, but am not entirely sure? Am I on the right track?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't this work as it is? http://jsfiddle.net/X3aTz/

Comment: Hi, yes, it works on jsfiddle, but not on my localhost for some reason? Very strange..

Comment: Check your developer console for any errors. Check your scripts (both jQuery and your application code) resolve to the right file and aren't 404'ing

Comment: as of 1.7 `delegate` is superseded by `on`.. what is the version of jQuery that you are trying in your local environment, and have you checked if you have got any error in debugging the code?

Comment: @optimusprime619: (nice name btw) Even though `on()` has replaced `delegate()`, `delegate()` still exists and will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701884/filter-content-using-checkboxes-jquery/10701958#comment13894230_10701958) that you're using jQuery 1.3

jQuery's [`delegate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was introduced in 1.4.2, so won't be available. You'll have to use a later version of jQuery (any reason why you're using such an old version?).

If you open your developer console (F12 shortcut in Chrome), you should see an error saying that `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'delegate'`

If you *need* to use jQuery 1.3, try:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.tags').bind('change', function(e) {
        var that = e.originalEvent.target;

        if ($(that).is('input:checkbox')) {
            var $lis = $('.results > li ').hide();
            //For each one checked
            $('input:checked ').each(function() {
                $lis.filter('.' + $(that).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Which you can see [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/X3aTz/3)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.results > li').hide();

            $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
                $('.results > li').hide();
                $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                    $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                });
            });
        });      ​
```

for live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/Ddnuh/

Comment: @Matt, Thanks, I was using the wrong version of jquery, it works with  `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js`. Thanks again, and apologies for my poor formatting. Back to my original question. Am I heading in the right direction trying to mimic the effect of the house of Fraser site?

Comment: @AndrewCookson: I can't see why not. If you start to get a lot of elements inside the `<ul class="results"/>`, the next step would be retrieve the list from AJAX on demand rather than include all content from page start. There's [`$('.results').load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this once

```
 $(function(){
        $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
            var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
            //For each one checked
            $('input[type="checked"]:checked').each(function() {
                    $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `[type="checked"]`?... not to mention your quotes are mis-matched.

Comment: hi I run the console and: missing ) after condition

        {

        checkbox.html (line 39, col 6)
 
        $("div.tags").delegate is not a function
        

        $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change',   function  () {

Comment: hi I'm using jquery:         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Matt, my scripts are inline, so should not be a problem with 404...formatting code on here for the first time is a struggle :)

Comment: Reversing it with: `$(function(){
        $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
            var $divs = $('.results > div').show();
            //For each one checked
            $('input:checked').each(function() {
                    $divs.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).hide();
            });
        });
  });` It's a little closer to what I'm aiming for...

Comment: That's total nonsense, scrap the last comment